# How can I demonstrate this probability equation?

Tags: probability

I have seen several times the following equation:

$$\sum_y P_{X|Y}(x|y) P_{Y|Z}(y|z) = P_{X|Z}(x|z)$$

How can I demonstrate this result? Does the result hold in general or we need some conditions?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right-hand side can be written as $\sum_y P_{X\mid (Y,Z)} (x\mid y, z) P_{Y \mid Z} (y \mid z)$ by the law of total probability. In general, this is not equal to the left-hand side. However, equality will hold if $P_{X \mid Y}(x \mid y) = P_{X \mid (Y,Z)}(x \mid y, z)$ for all $y$; this condition is the definition of "$X$ and $Z$ are conditionally independent given $Y$."